# Creating social buttons without an iFrame and tracking

Tags: javascript, iframe, social-networking, facebook-social-plugins

I've decided against embedding my share buttons with an iFrame. This is to reduce the load time. I am using this method instead:

```
<!-- Facebook -->
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.mywebsite.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="/images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook"</a>

<!-- Twitter -->
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=http://www.mywebsite.co.uk&amp;text=Website name" target="_blank"><img src="/images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter"></a>

<!-- Google+ -->
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.mywebsite.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="/images/google.png" alt="Google"></a>

<!-- LinkedIn -->
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=http://www.mywebsite.co.uk" target="_blank">/images/linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn"></a>
```

Will each social network still keep track of how many times the page has been shared should I decide to introduce more advanced buttons in the future?

Thanks!

Comment: Wether with iFrame or without - where do you see in facebook how many times someone shared your website with a button on your site?

Comment: facebook will know where your visitors came from, whether you do it this way, or with the buttons they generated for you.

Comment: Thanks @TimothyGroote. Do you know if this is also the case with Twitter, Google+ and LinkedIn?

Comment: unfortunately not. still, it's probably safer to go with the pre-generated buttons.

Comment: Thanks buddy, thought as much.

Comment: You could simply place an facebook-logo as image and href it to your page.